# Some checkbox settings not applying

Tags: settings

When I change some Civi settings they do not get applied. It seems to be only when deselecting some checkboxes. For example, in Custom Fields I deselect: Collapse this set on initial display. It looks like its saved but when I go back to the settings it is still ticked.

I can tick: Collapse this set in Advanced Search. hit save and it stays ticked. But when I untick the box and it remains ticked.

When I deselect: Is this Custom Data Set active? - The settings are saved.

This also happens in the Edit Scheduled Reminder settings page. I untick: Record activity for automated email and hit save. When I go back into the settings for the reminder it is still ticked.

There are no obvious logs. CiviCRM 5.25.0, Drupal 7.70 , PHP 7.3.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.  I've confirmed it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and opened an issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1794

Comment: Thanks. Fixed in 5.26.1

Answer (score 2):

Have submitted [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17493) for the issue, can you apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17493.patch) or you will need to wait for 5.27 release.

For Schedule reminder you can apply the [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17494) as a patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17494.patch).